# The operation cannot be completed. The term store may be unavailable

Tags: error, term-store

When I tried to Custom Sort the sub-terms of a term, it gives me an error

> The operation cannot be completed. The term store may be unavailable.

However, this only happens with one term, I was able to custom sort the other terms and sub-terms, so I don't think it has anything to do with security or permissions. Any ideas of how to resolve this?

Comment: this might be an issue with permission, check this one http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e600edef-7a63-4ee1-bd45-3e91f2acbf81/managed-metadata-failed-to-read-from-or-write-to-database-refresh-and-try-again-if-the-problem?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After refreshing several times the problem still persisted. However, after some time I tried again, and it was working again.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue recently. In my case the managed metadata service was not working. When I checked that again I found that application pool was not running. When I started its application pool it start working smoothly.